# Solution of a Sylvester equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, control-theory

I'd like to solve $AX -BX + XC = D$, for the matrix $X$, where all matrices have real entries and $X$ is a rectangular matrix, while $B$ and $C$ are symmetric matrices and $A$ is formed by an outer product matrix (i.e, as $vv^T$ for some real vector $v$) while $D$ is 'not' symmetric. $A,B,C,D$ matrices are fixed while $X$ is the unknown.

How can this equation be solved? Secondly, is there any case, where the solution of this equation has a closed form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More generally, Sylvester's equation of the form 
$$AX+XB=C$$ can be put into the form
$$M\cdot \textrm{vec}X=L$$ for larger matrices $M$ and $L$.

Here $\textrm{vec}X$ is a stack of all columns of matrix $X$.

How to find the matrix $M$ and $L$, is shown in chapter 4 of this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Topics-Matrix-Analysis-Roger-Horn/dp/0521467136](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521467136)

Indeed, $M=(I\otimes A)+(B^T\otimes I)$, and $L=\textrm{vec}C$, where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.

Special case with $M$ invertible,  we have $\textrm{vec}X=M^{-1}L$.

Comment: Apart from the invertibility, are there other required conditions for this closed form to exist? Also, can I use the pseudoinverse of $M$, and would that be justified for this solution?

Comment: As usual for solving the equation $Ax=b$, if $A$ is not invertible then there are either infinitely many solutions or no solutions depending on $b$.

Comment: A similar description in wiki here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation  considers $X$ to be a square matrix. Is that the case, in the suggested book and in your answer? Because, in my question, $X$ is a rectangular matrix.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the matrices are square. It only requires that the products of matrices are well-defined.

Answer (score 4):

How about a small but concrete example of $AX + XB = C$:
$$\pmatrix{a_0 & a_1 \\a_2 & a_3}\pmatrix{x_0 \\ x_1} + \pmatrix{x_0 \\ x_1} b= \pmatrix{c_0 \\ c_1}$$

This gives a system of two equations:
\begin{align}
  a_0x_0 + a_1x_1+bx_0 &= c_0 \\
  a_2x_0 + a_3x_1+bx_1 &= c_1 \\
\end{align}
Which leads to the vectorized (using the Kroneker product formula for the Sylvester Equation):
$$\pmatrix{a_0 +b & a_1 \\a_2 & a_3+b}\pmatrix{x_0 \\ x_1} = \pmatrix{c_0 \\ c_1}$$

And depending on the determinant, it has a single solution. In this particular example, the $b$ as a scalar was transformed into $bI$ the scale of the identity. In higher dimensions, it will not generalize that way, you just have to follow the vectorization, and the dimension of the new equation will be a square of the multiple of the respective dimensions.