# Number of solutions $X$ to $AX=XB$ in $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

It is a well-known theorem that in an arbitrary field $F$, if $A$ is an $m\times m$ square matrix and $B$ is an $n\times n$ square matrix, then there is a unique $m\times n$ solution $X$ to the equation 
$$AX=XB$$
if and only if $A$ and $B$ share no eigenvalues.

My **question** is this: what can be said about the *number* of solutions $X\in \mathbb F_2$ to the above equation? Is the number of nonzero solutions equal to the number of common eigenvalues? If so, how can one prove this?

Comment: You probably mean the number of linearly independent solutions. Otherwise, it's obvious that the answer is false. Because if $X$ is a solution, so is $\lambda X$. Right? Does this theorem have a name? I'd like to see the proof.

Comment: You're right; I am actually working mostly in $\mathbb F_2$ so that specification isn't important, and I should mention that in my question. As for the theorem: I don't know if it has a name, but the equation is called a "Sylvester Equation" and the Wikipedia page has a proof of said theorem.

Comment: @stressedout It is [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

Comment: @stressedout  The unique solution, when it is unique, is $X = 0$.

Comment: Try Cecioni-Frobenius theorem..

Comment: The "well-known theorem" can't be true as stated for arbitrary fields.  What if $A = B$ with no eigenvalues (in the field $\mathbb F$)?

Comment: You're quoting wrongly the well-known theorem.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Yes. I was talking about its possible generalization. The OP hadn't mentioned that he/she was working in $\mathbb{F}_2$, so I assumed that we were working in $\mathbb{R}$.  @A.{Gamma}.  Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

$X$ maps each eigenvector of $B$ to either $0$ or an eigenvector of the same eigenvalue of $A$, since if $Bv = \lambda v$, $AX v = X B v = \lambda X v$.

Let's suppose for simplicity that $B$ is diagonalizable, with a basis $b_j$ of eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ that may or may not be eigenvalues of $A$.

For each $j$, we can choose $X b_j$ to be any member of the eigenspace of $A$ for $\lambda_j$, and once we have done that we have specified a solution $X$.  Thus the number of solutions for $X$ is the product over $j$ of the cardinalities of the eigenspaces of $A$ for $\lambda_j$ (note that this is $1$ if $\lambda_j$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$).

Answer (score 2):

Your statement of well-known theorem requires saying that the eigenvalues are in the algebraic closure of the given field $F$. This is an easy version of Cecioni-Frobenius theorem suggested in the comments by 'user'.

**Method 1 : Module Theory**

Under your assumption for matrices $A$, $B$, $X$, define 
$$
C_{A,B}=\{X\in M_{m\times n}(F) \mid AX - XB = 0 \}.$$

Let $\nu_{A,B}$ be the dimension of $C_{A,B}$ over $F$. The actual version of Cecioni-Frobenius theorem gives a formula
$$
\nu_{A,B}=\sum_p(\deg p)\sum_{i,j} \min\{\lambda_{p,i}, \mu_{p,j}\}
$$
Here the first sum is over all irreducible polynomials $p$ which are common in the primary decompositions of $F[x]$-modules $M^A$ and $M^B$, and the indices $i, j$ of second double sum is from the partition $\lambda_p=\sum_i \lambda_{p,i}$ that indicates the powers of $p$ in $p$-primary part of $M^A$, $\mu_p=\sum_j \mu_{p,j}$ that of powers of $p$ in $p$-primary part of $M^B$.

Then the number of solutions to $AX=XB$ is $2^{\nu_{A,B}}$.

**Method 2 : Kronecker Product**

Alternatively, there is a module-theory-free way. You will have an advantage of not having to solve for eigenvalues of $A$, $B$. But, a disadvantage is that there is almost no hope for writing down an explicit formula for $\nu_{A,B}$. This is by Kronecker product, the method is mainly this: [Solution of a Sylvester equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353329/solution-of-a-sylvester-equation/353618#353618)

In our case, the equation $AX-XB=0$ can be written as 
$$
(I_n \otimes A - B^T \otimes I_m) \textrm{vec}(X)=0
$$
where $\textrm{vec}(X)$ is a stack of columns of $X$ in order.

Then perform elementary row operations on the $mn\times mn$ matrix  $I_n \otimes A - B^T \otimes I_m$. Find the number of free-variables, which is $\nu_{A,B}$. Again the number of solutions to $AX=XB$ is $2^{\nu_{A,B}}$.

Answer (score 2):

To ask for the number of solutions of $f(X)=AX-XB=0$ is equivalent to ask for $dim(\ker(f))$. Moreover, the required dimension is the same over the underlying field $K$ or over its algebraic closure $\overline{K}$.

If we stack the considered matrices row by row, then $f=A\otimes I-I\otimes B^T$. Let $(\lambda_i),(\mu_i)$ be the spectra of $A,B$ in $\overline{K}$. Since the functions $X\mapsto AX,X\mapsto XB$ commute, $spectrum(f)=(\lambda_i-\mu_j)_{i,j}$. Unfortunately, that does not give the required dimension; we can only say that $\ker(f)\not= 0$ iff $degree(gcd(\chi_A,\chi_B))\geq 1$, where $\chi_.$ is the characteristic polynomial.

The Cecioni-Frobenius (CF) theorem (1910) provides a solution if we can calculate the invariant factors of $A,B$.

$dim(\ker(f))=\nu_{A,B}=\sum_{i,j}degree(gcd(d_i(A),d_j(B))$ where $d_i$ is the $i^{th}$ invariant factor.

I had heard about this theorem in 2009 and then I had completely forgotten about it. It was used by Byrnes-Gauger (1979) to show that

$A,B$ are similar iff $2\nu_{A,B}=\nu_{A,A}+\nu_{B,B}$.

Note that, in great dimension, the invariant factor algorithm (the calculation of the Smith normal form of $xI-A$) is not effective. Fortunately, Byrnes-Gauger before proved (1977) this extraordinary result

$A,B$ are similar iff $\det(xI-A)=\det(xI-B),rank(A\otimes I-I\otimes A)=rank(B\otimes I-I\otimes B)=rank(A\otimes I-I\otimes B)$.

Here is an example of using the CF theorem

let $J_k$ be the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $k$, $A=diag(J_3,J_2),B=diag(J_4,J_1)$. Then the Smith forms are

$S(A)=diag(1,1,1,x^2,x^3),S(B)=diag(1,1,1,x,x^4)$.

Then $\nu_{A,B}=deg(gcd(x^2,x))+deg(gcd(x^2,x^4))+deg(gcd(x^3,x))+deg(gcd(x^3,x^4))=7$.

Comment: (+1) for mentioning Byrnes-Gauger.

Comment: Actually, there are 3 papers from Byrnes and Gauger, but none from 1979. Which is the one that has the characterization $A,B$ similar iff $2\nu_{A,B}=\nu_{A,A}+\nu_{B,B}$?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a special case of Sylvester equation.

Let $A$ and $B$ be operators with spectra $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(B)$, respectively.  If $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(B)$ are disjoint, then the equation
$AX-XB=Y$ has a unique solution $X$ for every $Y$.  Moreover, the solution is given by $X=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^{-n-1}YB$.  Hence, for $Y=0$ unique solution is $X=0$ as Robert Israel claimed.

The proof of the theorem above can be found in Bhatia's Matrix Analysis.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both solutions. Then $A(X_1+X_2)=AX_1+AX_2=X_1B+X_2B=(X_1+X_2)B$. Thus, $X_1+X_2$ is a solution. So the number of solutions can be $0$, $1$, or infinity. This is a common situation in linear algebra: you either have no solutions, a unique solution, or infinite solutions.

Comment: @Accumulation Not true in $\mathbb F_2$, since $X+X=0$. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Nor in any finite field, since there are only finitely many $m \times n$ matrices there.

Comment: I wrote my answer before the question was edited to say that it's over $\mathbb F_2$. If the downvote is due to me assuming that it's over the reals, I don't think that's an unreasonable assumption.